# Finding a Discord Channel ID using its name

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been using discord.js 11.4.4 for quite some time now, due to hard drive failure, I had to redownload discord.js and decided it was time to get the newest version as well but came to some problems along the way.

I am looking to find the `channel` ID for a `channel` that I want, I wish to search for the channel by `channel` name.

Code I was using in the past:

```js
message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name")
  .then(channel => console.log(`Channel ID: ${channel.id}`));
```

I would then to store the id into a variable that I would be able to call on later.

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is exactly

Comment: @Shizzle can you please provide me a way to find the id of the channel called general for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on v11 then its

```js
message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name").id;
```

if you re on v12 then its

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name").id;
```

[Collection#find](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) returns a channel object , you just need to get `id` from from it

Answer (score 0):

Most of the collections have been converted to a new Manager system in version 12 which, among other things, contains a collection called 'cache'.  Asside from the need to redirect to use this cache property, the functionality is mostly the same when retrieving.

```
let ch = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name");
console.log(`Channel ID: ${ch.id}`));
```

The big advantages of the Manager system are that it allows for a better structured method system in other areas.  For example v11's 
`guild.createChannel();` becomes `guild.channels.create();` which just makes so much more sense in an object oriented approach.

This specific manager is documented here: [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannelManager)

There is a full [upgrade guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start) as well

Comment: (node:14108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.channels.cache.find(...).then is not a function

this error code appears.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't return a promise.  Though, it never did so I'm not sure how your first code could've worked on v11.